# Enabling and disabling specific buttons in and Enum in C#

Tags: button, parameters, enums

i have this enum called ScoreType.

```
 public enum ScoreType {
        Ones, Twos, Threes, Fours, Fives, Sixes,
        SubTotal, BonusFor63Plus, SectionATotal,
        ThreeOfAKind, FourOfAKind, FullHouse,
        SmallStraight, LargeStraight, Chance, Yahtzee,
        YahtzeeBonus, SectionBTotal, GrandTotal
    }
```

I would like to in the EnableScoreButton method to enable the specified button corresponding to the ScoreType parameter of 'combo'.

```
public void EnableScoreButton(ScoreType combo) {
            //SOMTHING.Enabled = true;

        }
```

Could you please show me how to do this?

Comment: What language are we talking about?

Comment: C# sorry i forgot to add it